# Prove must exist subsequence converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

Let a and b be two scalars and a is less than b, prove that for any sequence in $[a,b]$ there must be a subsequence converging to some point in $[a,b]$

Comment: $[a,b]$ is compact.

Comment: that's my typo, I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if $a = 0, b = 1$, and the sequence is $1/n$? This sequence converges to $0$, which is not in $(0,1)$. The reason is that you need to consider the **closed** interval $[a,b]$. Then the result follows from compactness (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem%20this)).